# UART3 RX/TX mode doesn't work for Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4!

Tags: pi-4, uart

I am using Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4:

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.82-v7l+ #1605 SMP Thu Dec 8 15:21:38 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I've tried to access UART3, after I enabled it on /boot/config.txt:

```
# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README
dtoverlay=disable-bt

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=uart3

#list serial's
# ls -al /dev | grep ttyAMA
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           7 Dec 21 08:22 serial0 -> ttyAMA0
crw-rw----  1 root dialout 204,  64 Dec 21 08:22 ttyAMA0
crw-rw----  1 root dialout 204,  65 Dec 21 09:12 ttyAMA1
```

Info 's about GPIO 's:

```
i# sudo raspi-gpio get 4,5,6,7
GPIO 4: level=1 fsel=3 alt=4 func=TXD3 pull=NONE
GPIO 5: level=1 fsel=3 alt=4 func=RXD3 pull=UP
GPIO 6: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=NONE


# dtoverlay -h uart3
Name:   uart3

Info:   Enable uart 3 on GPIOs 4-7. BCM2711 only.

Usage:  dtoverlay=uart3,<param>

Params: ctsrts                  Enable CTS/RTS on GPIOs 6-7 (default off)
```

I am using a terminal emulation program in WIN10 to communicate via serial with my RPI. In CM4, using "cat" linux cmd, I've received successfully messages (value 20) from WIN10 emulator, check attached image:
[image: Capture1.PNG]

But, when I've tried to write something from RPI to WIN10 using "echo" linux command, it doesn't work!

`echo 1 > /dev/ttyAMA1`

I don't know if flow control pins ( 6 , 7 ) should be enable....

Do you have any suggestions?

*P.S. I've used an USB - RS485 convertor between RPI and my WIN10 PC*

Comment: RS485 is not RS232.  It sounds like you need more than a terminal emulator (RS232) at the Pi end.  So, yes, you probably need additional signal wires.

Comment: Check out https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/12/06/what-is-rs485-and-its-difference-between-rs232/